# My power supply tripped the RCD

Tags: protection, fuses

I also posted this at All About Circuits but I thought I would get some more opinions as I'm quite worried.

I was using my power supply to power an electronics project (Super OSD.) The power supply is a TM035-3/GM035-3 0-3A 0-35V CC/CV power supply. When I turned the supply off, then on again, it made a little pop sound from inside and the RCD for the sockets tripped. (Lights remained.) It also blew the 5A mains input fuse. Obviously both safety features helped protect against a bad failure. After untripping the RCD and replacing the fuse, all is well - it still works perfectly fine. I am now a little concerned about how the power supply blew both the fuse and tripped the RCD! I have turned the supply on and off many times before. I am thinking inrush current but why only this time?

Comment: What is a "RCD"?

Comment: @W5VO, residual current device, similar to a GFCI in the US. It trips on an imbalance between live and neutral currents which indicates an earth fault.

Answer (score 1):

Probably an elctrolytic cap inside the PSU has blown open circuit, can you open it up to check?  If there is not any noticable ripple on your output I would not be too concerned.

Comment: No ripple... well, a few millivolts, but it has always had that since I got it 3 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

To trip an rcd the power supply must have conducted to earth. Are you sure it was an rcd or just a resetable circuit breaker?  If it was an rcd then there must be a loose wire inside the psu. No part of a mains psu should connect to earth other than the output circuitry and the incoming EMC filter.

If it was not an rcd then probably a blown electrolytic.

Comment: -1  I have seen several devices with blow an RCD/GFCI where there was no possible conductive path to earth.  The most recent was a small refrigerator with a 2-prong plug and sitting on an isolated platform. I have no idea what the actual mechanism was to cause the it to blow, but it wasn't current "conducted to earth".

Comment: @David - We suspect that this is Yet Another Tony Stewart Sockpuppet. You also had to downvote one of his other answers.